OWIN middleware, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error when adding header to streaming response
I have a simple middleware class that gets a "Correlation Id" from the incoming request and then add that "Correlation Id" to the response. It works fine for most request but when streaming data from AWS S3 I get "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error. If I removed the middleware it works fine.
Here is the middleware
public class ApplicationHeaders : OwinMiddleware
{
    private readonly OwinMiddleware _next;

    public ApplicationHeaders(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var correlationId = GetCorrelationId(request);

        await _next.Invoke(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
        context.Response.Headers[RequestHeaders.CorrelationIdName] = correlationId;
    }

    private string GetCorrelationId(IOwinRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Headers[RequestHeaders.CorrelationIdName]))
        {
            //add a header as well. and save the generated value
            request.Headers[RequestHeaders.CorrelationIdName] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        return request.Headers[RequestHeaders.CorrelationIdName];
    }

}

Any ideas on why adding a header causes the problem?
